# Programmatically set '?selectableItemBackground' on Android view

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-cardview

In xml, I often do this to emulate `onClick` effect:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground">

    ...

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Is there any way to access `?selectableItemBackground` in java?

Answer (score 239, accepted):

For **appcompat** you can use,

```
TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground, outValue, true);
cardView.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
```

Comment: I've been searching a lot and I've found a lot of answers, but this certainly is the best one. Thank you so much!

Comment: not working for me I making an Image View programmatically and setting this resource alongwith clickable and focusable true

Comment: This changes background not foreground, so if you already have a custom background for the view it replaces it. I don't know how this can be the right answer

Comment: Comes up as purple. Any way to change the color?

Comment: this is helpful.

Comment: this raised `Resources$NotFoundException`

Comment: How to do this in the case of `style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"` on a Button?

Answer (score 62):

For those who work with Kotlin, here are some extensions functions to add Ripple on Android View type :

```
private fun View.addRipple() = with(TypedValue()) {
    context.theme.resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground, this, true)
    setBackgroundResource(resourceId)
}

private fun View.addCircleRipple() = with(TypedValue()) {
    context.theme.resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackgroundBorderless, this, true)
    setBackgroundResource(resourceId)
}
```

Comment: With android.R.attr... will support the API level >= 21, rather if use R.attr... it'd be backward compatible.

Comment: When I click cardview it disappears!

Comment: addCircleRipple() does not support API level < 21, therefore I'd suggest:

`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {  
    view.addCircleRipple()
}`

Comment: for `CardView` you have to set the `foreground`, not the `background`.

Answer (score 27):

I was looking for the same solution. I slightly changed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37987915/2212770) answer to make it more suitable for the asked question. Call the following code from your constructor.

```
private void setClickableAnimation(Context context)
{
    TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
    context.getTheme().resolveAttribute( 
        android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground, outValue, true);        
    setForeground(getDrawable(context, outValue.resourceId));
}
```

Answer (score 9):

For Kotlin I'm using

```
binding.yourCoolView.apply {
    background = with(TypedValue()) {
        context.theme.resolveAttribute(
            androidx.appcompat.R.attr.selectableItemBackground, this, true)
        ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, resourceId)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

For people using Kotlin, this is an extended version of @Nicolas answer. If you are using `CardView`, you need to change the `foreground`, not the `background`.

**Code**

```kotlin
fun View.addBackgroundRipple() = with(TypedValue()) {
    context.theme.resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground, this, true)
    setBackgroundResource(resourceId)
}

fun View.addBackgroundCircleRipple() = with(TypedValue()) {
    context.theme.resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackgroundBorderless, this, true)
    setBackgroundResource(resourceId)
}

fun View.addForegroundRipple() = with(TypedValue()) {
    context.theme.resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground, this, true)
    foreground = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, resourceId)
}

fun View.addForegroundCircleRipple() = with(TypedValue()) {
    context.theme.resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackgroundBorderless, this, true)
    foreground = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, resourceId)
}
```

**Usage**

```kotlin
// Background ripple
linearLayout.addBackgroundRipple()

// Foreground ripple
cardView.addForegroundRipple()
```

Comment: @Nicolas without an 'H' ;) 
Thanks for updating the answer anyway

Answer (score 7):

You should reference it as

`android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground`

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Wirling answer we can use foreground to set both the color and the ripple effect

Note: Foreground requires android API level 23(M) and above:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {  
    TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
    getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground, outValue, true);
    view.setForeground(getDrawable(getContext(), outValue.resourceId));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try below code.

```
int[] attrs = new int[]{R.attr.selectableItemBackground};
TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
int backgroundResource = typedArray.getResourceId(0, 0);
cardView.setBackgroundResource(backgroundResource);
cardView.setClickable(true);
typedArray.recycle();
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this code doesn't make sense to me, what's the point of obtaining `TypedArray` if you're not getting any resource from it?

Answer (score -1):

From a fragment:

```
TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
requireContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground, outValue, true);
cardView.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
```

From an adapter declaring in its constructor the context or the same fragment:

```
TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
fragment.requireContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground, outValue, true);
holder.cardView.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
```