# InflateException while inflating CardView to Recyclerview on android device with android 4.4

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am facing this InflateException when I try to inflate CardView/RecyclerView on an android device with version 4.4 please note that i am not facing this issue in any device with version more than 4.4 or Kitkat.

Please is the stacktrace of the exception

```
02-02 01:59:10.526 2288-2288/app.learnkannada.com.learnkannadakannadakali E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                        Process: app.learnkannada.com.learnkannadakannadakali, PID: 2288
                                                                                        android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                                            at adapter.ListViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(ListViewAdapter.java:68)
                                                                                            at adapter.ListViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(ListViewAdapter.java:28)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6365)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5563)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5448)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5444)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2224)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1551)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1511)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:595)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3600)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3036)
                                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                                            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:689)
                                                                                            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:473)
                                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:393)
                                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
                                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
                                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1912)
                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1109)
                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
                                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
                                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
                                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
                                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                            at java.lang
```

is it that RecyclerView/CardView are not supported in Kitkat? or any other reason? Please help.

Below is the code where exception occurred

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout_course, parent, false);
```

Below is the xml I am trying to inflate.

```
please find below is the xml code.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/cardview_compat_inset_shadow"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="0.9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textID"
                    android:text="Test Text"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="number"
                    android:id="@+id/sizeID"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: share your xml layout with question

Comment: @NileshRathod I have updated the xml. Please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Remove **`tools:targetApi="lollipop"`** from your `CardView`

And Also Use this

```
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Instead of this

```
 android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless
```

**CODE**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/cardview_compat_inset_shadow"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped me but I cannot get selectableItemBackgroundBorderless as it requires me to put targetApi. Now, how can I handle this programmatically so that I still use this effect for android versions above 4.4?

Comment: Set it inside the direct child of the `CardView`

Comment: How does removing `tools` from the xml help? AFAIK tools' attributes are removed when you create an APK?

Comment: @VarunAM this will help you my friend https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37987732/programatically-set-selectableitembackground-on-android-view

Comment: @NileshRathod Thank you so much :)

Comment: @VarunAM happy to you

Comment: @NileshRathod I have accepted it as answer now :-) Thanks for accepting the edit. If you feel this was a valid question, please upvote question also!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include a dependency for CardView.
To add dependency, add following line in your module gradle's depedency part

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:X.X.X'
}
```

(replace X with your version)

Make sure you are using vector images in ImageView with `app:srcCompat`.
If you are using vector images as top/bottom/right/left drawable or checkbox button, below 21 Vector images are not directly supported in drawable.

For more info on vector support, you can go through
[How to use vector drawables in Android API lower 21?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34417843/how-to-use-vector-drawables-in-android-api-lower-21/36661438)

Comment: Hi, I have already added the dependency. this issue is seen only on android device with version below lollipop. The above answer by nilesh has helped me. Please suggest if there is a way to give foreground effect programmatically.