# Delete ripple effect on recycler view item click programmatically

Tags: android

I need to delete ripple effect on a recycler view item click programmatically. This is because I reuse the adapter in several activities of my app, but there's a particular one where the items shouldn't be clickable, therefore I need to delete the ripple effect, otherwise it looks like it should do something on click, but it is not working.

The only way it works is by removing

```
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

on the view holder, but as I said, I can't do that because I'm reusing it, and it should show the ripple effect in several other activities.
Is there a way to disable it from a particular activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should let your adapter take in a parameter that determines whether to display the ripple or not.

So start by changing your adapters constructor:

```
MyAdapter(boolean shouldRipple)
```

Then you can set the item foreground in `onBindViewHolder`:

```
onBindViewHolder {

    itemView.setForeground(...)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do one thing. Instead of setting `android:foreground` by XML, You can set it programatically.

Whenever You do not need this foreground(ripple effect), simply set the `null`. And when you required this, then You can set this `?attr/selectableItemBackground` programatically.

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37987915/4211264) to set it programatically